# Flot ignoring null values at end of data

Tags: flot

I'm using Flot to build a chart, and null items at the end of the data collection are being ignored.

My code is below:

```
var d1 = [];    

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 1)
    d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);

for (var i = 4; i <= 10; i += 1)
    d1.push([i, null]);

function plotWithOptions() {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1], {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
}

plotWithOptions();</code>
```

Using Flot 0.8.1, this produces the following:

[image]

[JSFiddle of 0.8.1](http://jsfiddle.net/munr/YWPqS/1/)

Interestingly, using an older version of Flot (0.7), this produces the type of graph I'd expect, with the null items rendered as gaps:

[image]

[JSFiddle of 0.7](http://jsfiddle.net/munr/Dw2Fs/1/)

In 0.8.1, if I add a non-null item at the end, the null entries are shown as a gap, but this is different behavior from 0.7 where they are rendered regardless (and which is the behavior I am trying to achieve).

Is there a setting or something I need to change to achieve this?

Comment: Why not replace the `null`s with 0s?

Comment: @nneonneo Tried that first. It still causes a line to be rendered, whereas I want no line at all.  This isn't so obvious with a bar chart, but with a line chart, there is a sudden drop instead of a clean stop, which is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 1134 from this:

```
if (f.autoscale) {
```

To this:

```
if (f.autoscale !== false) {
```

I'll push the fix to master as soon as I finish testing to make sure this doesn't break anything else.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me spamming your answer here just to say 'thanks' for maintaining flot.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bug.  I suggest you file an Issue on their [github page](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues).

If you need to work around it, you can make a second series that isn't shown, and fill the values with 0 instead of null:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    d1.push([i, parseInt(Math.random() * 30)]);
    d2.push([i, 0]);
}

for (var i = 4; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    d1.push([i, null]);
    d2.push([i, 0]);
}
```

And then when you call `$.plot`, use options that show the bars for `d1` but nothing for `d2`:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [{
    data: d1
}, {
    bars: {
        show: false
    },
    lines: {
        show: false
    },
    data: d2
}], {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```

Working example from your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/YWPqS/2/

Comment: Thanks.  Eventually, I ended up using the older version (0.7) as there wasn't a specific reason to use the newer version, but your suggestion sounds like a viable workaround.  I'll look at filing a bug on Github later.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely sounds like a bug, and I think I know what might have caused it.  Please do open an issue, so I can let you know when it's fixed.

Comment: @DNS Thanks. I've logged this issue as requested (#1095).